# Update manager will keep installing forever

Tags: updates, update-manager

A few days ago I ran the update manager to see if there were any new updates to be downloaded. There were some updates, so I clicked the Download button. Once it finished, it asked me to install them as usual. However, it seems to be a problem with one specific update. The update manager starts installing it, but the progress bar stays for hours in the middle of the progress and a message appears in the details.

This is the update information before installing.

[image: update_information]

And these are the details that show up while installing.

[image: update_details]

After that, I tried to reboot the computer, but as you can see, the problem has not been solved by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that update manager waits for user input while showing changelog of the `unattended-upgrades` package. You can try to press <kbd>q</kbd> while it is shown.

Otherwise you should try to fix this manually from terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```